# Is it possible to persist a file in a docker image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, radix, docker-image

I want to prepare a base docker image that executes a command and produces a report. I want this to be persisted within the image for the next docker file. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to set a WORKDIR within your dockerfile e.g.

```
WORKDIR /data
```

and use a volume with the run command for the built image.

```
docker run -v /users/home/your_user/use_case_folder:/data -it your_image_tag /bin/bash
```

When you run your reports/predictions you have to write them to /data, then your files will be placed on your local system. You now can use the next 
Dockerfile and use the same volume mount, which is defined as WORKDIR within the new Dockerfile. Sharing the results within the image itself for another image is not possible as far as I know. You will always have to use an outside mounted File System or Database or sth. similar.

Maybe here you can find some infos too:
https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#restore-container-from-backup